# Can you use ascii codes in SELECT statements? Specifically the SOH character

Tags: oracle, select, oracle11g, ascii

I have the following simple select statement :

`select 'hello' || '|' || 'world' as MYVALUE from dual;`

This gives me 2 words, delimited by a pipe.

I want to swap out the pipe delimeter for something else, such as the Ascii SOH character.

How can I use an ascii code in a select statement, such as `\u01` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CHR function returns the character for any ASCII code e.g. to get the character with ASCII code 1:

```
SELECT CHR(1) FROM DUAL;
```